# When I run a vbs bot it doesn't work becauuse it can't create an object so how to solve it?

Tags: object, vbscript, bots

I am trying to make an internet bot for a little job but I don't know vbs that much and every time I try to run the code I have (800A01AD) error code.

Here is the code:

```
Set Webbrowser = CreateObject("IntrnetExplorer.Application")
Webbrowser.Statusebar = False
Webbtowser.Menubar = False
Webbrowser.Toolbar = False
Webbrowser.Visible = True
```

I have tried to write the code in editor instead of notepad but it didn't work.

Comment: How are you running that code? Please also show the complete, unaltered error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code:

```
Set Webbrowser = CreateObject("IntrnetExplorer.Application")
```

The code should be:

```
Set Webbrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```

[This is the naming convention used in Microsoft website.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa752084)